# Tascam 40x settings to use internal and external microphones simultaneously

Tags: tascam

I have an external Condenser mic and I want to record simultaneously from the 2 internal mics and from the external one.

Which settings do I need to do this? Stereo? Mono? Dual?
What about source mode?

Answer (score 1):

Use 4ch mode. See manual page28.